# How to use ZoneMinder on 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, video, zoneminder

I've installed the `zoneminder` package (had to start MySQL, otherwise it can't even install). I've also started apache after that. But I can't find how to actually get to the web interface. localhost/zm gets me to one of my Drupal installations.

Comment: did you follow the post-install instructions in the readme? More info here: http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Documentation#Introduction

Comment: Yes, it's running. No, I thought it was more ready to use if it's already in repos.

Comment: BTW, where is that readme exactly? It's not part of the package.

Comment: Ok, it worked to get the admin page, thanks, @Rinzwind Will you add this as an answer? `sudo ln -s /etc/zm/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/zoneminder.conf` `sudo a2enconf zoneminder`

Comment: ok :D I got the readme from the source install (did not have Ubuntu on me so could not install the package ;-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For connecting to Apache you need the following commands:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/zm/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/zoneminder.conf 
sudo a2enconf zoneminder
```

The 1st one makes a symlink to the configuration of apache and tells it to incude the zoneminder configuration. The 2nd one enables the configuration.